# Peltier heat-pump, insulation between hot and cold chambers

Tags: arduino, peltier, cooling

I have made a decent heat pump, with 4 x peltier elements each at 48W. Each element will be switched with a separate relay. I will later install DS18B20 sensors in the heatsinks, embedded in thermal paste. Right now my problem is to choose the best, most workable insulation material. It will be placed as a thermal barrier between the hot and cold chambers, which each have their own airflow running.

I chose PU-foam, which is popularly used for e.g. water heaters. The label says it is a cancer risk, so I was wondering what you lot would recommend as an alternative. PU-foam will harden, and make it impossible to remove my pump for repairs etc.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/ has a HVAC tag where you can probably find much information.

Comment: Don't eat the PU-foam and you wont get cancer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with electronics and its a shopping question.

Comment: It has to do with housing electronics safely. Don't banish me to the DIY stackexchange.

Comment: Please let the question stand for 12 hours more. Then I'll close it myself.

Comment: polystyrene, vermiculite, and fiberglass come to mind. add a thin reflective barrier as well.

Comment: What material should I use for the thin barrier? Should it be in the middle?

Comment: foil or mylar; anything cheap and highly-reflective...

Comment: In the middle, between the two heatsinks, or in each chamber, before the insulation layer? Post it as an answer please, I believe this is the right answer for this question.

Comment: @dandavis post this as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: you want to reflect the heat away from the hot side to keep any thermal radiation from absorbing into the cold side. you probably don't mind the cold side "leaking" and absorbing radiant energy from the environment. an "emergency blanket" would work well. remember convection, conduction, and radiation, and work to reduce all three energy transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I want to make something clear. TECs are horribly inefficient for certain applications. You're using 16 Amps for a heat pump! That's a lot of current, and is [more than lethal](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~p616/safety/fatal_current.html) if you don't know what you're doing. Overall, if you are doing a central HVAC project (I assume, as you commented that this question had to do with housing electronics), you're better off using a condenser system as that would be more efficient than your 4 TECs.

Concerning your insulation issue: if you're worried about that California cancer warning label - don't. They have to put that label on there because it's legally bound by [Proposition 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_65_(1986)). It just means that there are ingredients that are found to cause cancer, but it doesn't mean that are in high enough quantities to *actually cause* cancer. That said, it *also* doesn't tell if it **is** in high enough quantities to cause cancer, so using PPE anyways when dealing with this kind of stuff is a good call. I actually own a organizer bucket that has that Proposition 65 warning for a couple of years now, and as far as I can tell, i'm not dead.

Also, don't worry about repairing TEC units - *because you can't*. They are either working or broken, there isn't an in-between. :)

Comment: I have replacement peltier elements, but if set in PU-foam I can't disassemble the heat pump. Thanks for your advice. What is this condenser system you would choose over a heat pump?

Comment: @user2497 A condenser system is the heat pump system used in bigger things like refrigerators and central HVAC units. Ever seen that fan-thing on the side of someone's house? That would be the condenser unit, which removes heat from the compressed freon gas, and makes it cold again for reuse.

Comment: I thought using freon was prohibited now. That's an excellent solution. I understand this type of system somewhat. Is it economic to build one?

Comment: @user2497 It's currently in the process of being phased-out, but it still isn't finished. **On the subject of economics**: It depends. Various factors that determine price are, but are not limited to: The size of the system, individual components, utilities, and more. You need to determine if the economics outweigh the time and energy to get this running. This is a decision that really cannot be made on a whim. You need to do research on components, and what the system is actually used for.

Comment: What are your thoughts on using cooling fluid for cars instead of freon?

Comment: @user2497 I also recommend that further questions like these be redirected to the DIY Stack Exchange. This place is really meant ***for the design, construction, and applications of electric circuits, components, and systems.*** I won't vote to close this question because you're [sorta] new here, but other people in this community might not be so forgiving, especially to newcomers. I believe you would receive a much more positive response on DIY StackExchange. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @user2497 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59332/discussion-between-gnimmargorp-and-user2497).

Comment: I looked at bending copper pipes for a grill that would absorb heat, but temporarily decided on a peltier-based device. The grill would absorb heat from the air, and dissipate it into a heatsink. A larger version of a CPU water cooling system, I suppose. For now, I have drilled holes into my two large heatsinks, and embedded a mesh of soldered copper wire (1.5mm) into it. A system like this magical condenser you talk about would be much better.

Comment: I appreciate it, please post your final thoughts as an answer, and I'll close it.

Comment: @user2497 ***On the subject of TEC Units***: Peltiers should never be used for big projects. They are horribly inefficient, and have a high power demand for low output. ***On the subject of Proposition 65***: Wear PPE if you're feeling nervous, otherwise, ignore at your own discretion. ***On the subject of central HVAC***: Compressors aren't magic. They just take the hot gases, and cool them off much like a radiator does on a automobile. ***On the subject of freon substitution***: Certain things were made for certain applications. Using another than the required might not end well.

Comment: @user2497 Oh, and don't forget to accept an answer! It really helps us! Many new users leave answers unaccepted and completely forget about it. Every bit counts! :)

Comment: Yes, please post as an answer instead of a comment. You've been most helpful.

Comment: @user2497 the post you've been commenting on ***IS*** an answer! Just click the checkmark button underneath the upvote and downvote buttons!

Comment: Well, I am given to thinking that freon will not expand much when heated, and car coolant will expand as water will (the stuff I've seen appears water-based, with oil and other hooey in it). But it doesn't matter if I pump it around nice and quiet-like.

Comment: What do you think about adapting a few large water cooling systems for CPU (the fans themselves are typically 7-8W), and keeping the heatsinks heated from such a system, using car coolant? I can just push the hot air out.